# Using Google Maps V3 API causes page to Refresh Many Many Times!

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API V3 and my page loads a map with 5 markers in it. Now whenever I load the page, I notice that the refresh button on my Chrome browser keeps changing to a 'Stop' icon that looks like a 'X' then back to the 'Refresh Page' icon and back to the 'X' icon again for about 3 seconds before the map is fully loaded and appears.  This is really puzzling, any idea how to get rid of it, or what causes it?

I only notice this in Chrome, not in FF or IE.

Comment: Look at the network tab in chrome's developer tools (CTRL+SHIFT+J) and see if gives you any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since approximately mid-May, I have noticed Google Maps doing that even using the direct webservice.  It matters not if it is Firefox, Konquerer, Safari, or SeaMonkey.  Chrome seems to do it worse.

As such, I don't think it is something you can fix.  Just wait for Google to fix their service.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I thought I did something wrong. Didn't notice that when I first started in May. http://www.google.com/maps doesnt show that refreshing problem though

Answer (score 0):

Google lead me here, I had almost a similar problem with the page consistently refreshing all of its content, the problem was caused by JavaScript variable naming clashes with google's own script.
for example: try "`var mylocation`", "`var mymarker`" instead of "`var location`", "`var marker`"